# https://stackoverflow.com/conduct displays 404 - Linked in the blog

Tags: bug, code-of-conduct

The code of conduct announcement blog just went out, yet the link to the code of conduct page in it yields a 404 - page not found.

Seems like a bug.

https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

This is on latest version of google chrome / windows 8.1